# Is there dataprovider concept in protractor?

Tags: mocha.js, protractor

I want to use a data provider in a Protractor based test to run the same test for multiple set of data. I am expecting it to work very similar to testng data provider.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that this is responsibility of particular test framework you are using with Protractor (e.g. Jasmine, Mocha,...).

AFAIK these frameworks doesn't have parametrized test support. But in our tests we did it this way and it worked for us perfectly:

```
    var testCases = [
        { param1: 'testcase1Param1', param2: 'testCase1Param2'  },
        { param1: 'testcase2Param1', param2: 'testCase2Param2'  },
    ];

    /*jshint -W083 */ //Disable warning for function created inside loop
    //this is parametrized test and it's better readable this way.
    testCases.forEach(function (testCase){
        describe('for test case: param1" ' + testCase.param1 +
                ' and param2: "' + testCase.param2 + '"', function(){
           //do your testing
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**

There is question in comment how to keep parameters in separate file. This falls down to the test suite configuration and how it handles modularity. So far I saw these approaches:

- Jasmine suite based on one major HTML file. In this case you can include your test cases file before the test class via `<script>` HTML tag. Take a look here: http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Standalone_Distribution
- Karma based test suite with RequireJs for handling dependencies. With this configuration you can import your file via standard RequireJs mechanisms. This would involve some research around [Karma](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) and [RequireJs](http://requirejs.org/). BTW, when you are using Protractor, you are testing AngularJs apps and Karma ist test tool made by Angular team.

Karma can be integrated with various Test frameworks and Module systems. So if you want some other style of handling modules (e.g. CommonJs), you can do it easily with Karma.

Comment: What do you mean by "externalize test data"?

Comment: Code shows that you have maintained all test data in same file where test case sits. But in my case I want to keep test data in a separate file. How can I parametrize test case where test data comes from a different file?

Comment: Would `mocha-testdata` be relevant?

Comment: Looking at that library doc, yes it is relevant. Why don't you create another answer instead of comment?